# Where to get the network NIC's firmware rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw?

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, debian

I am installing Debian testing version wheezy on my Asus X53Sc with Intel Centrino Wireless-N 100.
I have a problem with my wifi connection. When I try to connect to the Internet with the wireless connection, an error occurs:

> Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw for module r8169.

I installed successfully the iwlwifi-100-5.ucode, but now I have this error.

Any ideas or suggestions to resolve the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likely in the `firmware-realtek` package.

Here is the [detail](http://packages.debian.org/sid/firmware-realtek)

Is it listed if you do

```
dpkg --get-selections *firmware*
```

If not, you can `apt-get install firmware-realtek`